# LinkedIn API V2 - Can't get summary, skills and headline

Tags: linkedin-api

I'd like to get summary, skills and headline when signing in but apparently I can't use r_basicprofile on LinkedIn's V2 API because it's deprecated. I'm using r_liteprofile, but when using that I can't retrieve these 3 fields.

r_fullprofile isn't a solution due to project's deadline, as I understand you have to apply for this permission on LinkedIn and this request can take up to 60 business days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id

You can use r_basicprofile in V2 but you have to apply for Linkedin partner program 
if they will approved then you can use

60 days is maximum time 
mostly they will take action within 1 week 
my my case they approved in 3 days only